# Passwords in PreferenceActivity screen?

Tags: android

I'm implementing a PreferenceActivity, which would ask the user for username and password. 
I'll use EditTextPreference for the username, but what element do I need to have a "password input", which will hide the inputted data (i.e. change to dots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should also be an EditText, but you configure it to "password"-mode.

See
[android:password](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3apassword) or [setTransformationMethod(TransformationMethod)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29)

Answer (score 4):

As `android:password` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#password). You should instead use [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType):

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextView and in XML file make its property `android:password = "true"`